# implicit dynamic linking vs explicit dynamic linking - which is more effective?

Tags: c, dynamic, linker, implicit

There are two ways to link a shared library .
one named implicit dynamic linking and one named explicit dynamic linking.
I have googled some doc not found docs tells the difference on efficiency of the two .
Take a linux .so file as example . my doubt is : the implicit linking compare with the explicit way , will the explicit way cause more IO or cpu or memory somehow ?
Wondering which way is more effective and why ?
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, implicit dynamic linking is the fact of saying that your program needs the library in order to run, by adding the library in the dependency section of your program. If the library isn't found at the start of the program, the program simply won't be executed.

Explicit dynamic linking is using a function like "LoadLibrary" (windows) or "dlopen" (Linux) in order to load a library at runtime. It's exactly what a plugin is, and how you can code it.

Now, doing an explicit dynamic linking is going to add work and complexity, and I don't see any reason for it to be more efficient than an implicit dynamic linking. You use explicit dynamic linking only when you cannot do otherwise, like loading a library depending on some runtime value.

Comment: So with "implicit" it is the loader and the OS that make sure the libraries are available, and with "explicit" it is the programmer. And of course a mix is also possible.

Comment: Also: some Windows DLLs are not loaded implicitly, such as `RICHED32.DLL`. Without a `LoadLibrary` call the program won't start (or will crash).

Comment: thanks for answer . Take a linux .so file as example . my doubt is : the implicit linking compare with the explicit way , will the explicit way cause more IO or cpu or memory somehow ?

Comment: From the point of view of your program only, yes, because you will have to call extra function (that perform I/O indeed) and retain the information in runtime (so memory will be taken). However, those same operation will be done rigth before executing your program, so globaly, maybe it's the same. What I can be sure is that worrying about memory consuption, extra IO / CPU is probably useless since those operation should be done juste once at runtime. If you open/close freneticly in a while loop, yes, it will be bad, but it's the same as open/close a picture in order to display it in a GUI[...]

Comment: [...] or any other operation like allocate memory, freeing just rigth after and allocate it again (luckily, the inner allocation mecanisme may prevent performance drop in that case, since when you free the memory, it doesn't really give back the memory to the OS). In this kind of case, it the algorithm that is broken, not the fact to load a dll/so.

Comment: understood . thanks for sharing .